# Find $T$ given matrix with respect to basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If 
$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & 2 \\
-2 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$

is the matrix representation of a linear transformation $T : P_2 (x) \to P_2 (x)$
with respect to the basis $\{1 - x,x(1 - x),x(1 + x)\}$, find $T$.

Also find $T$ in the case that the basis is $\{1,1+ x,1+ x^ 2 \}. $

How to proceed in this question?

Answer (score 1):

Since $1=1-x+\frac12x(1-x)+\frac12x(1+x)$,\begin{align}T(1)&=T(1-x)+\frac12T\bigl(x(1-x)\bigr)+\frac12T\bigl(x(1+x)\bigr)\\&=1-x+\frac12\times(-2)x(1-x)+\frac12x(1+x)\\&=1-\frac32x+\frac32x^2.\end{align}You can compute $T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$ in a similar way and this will give you $T$.

Let $b=\{1-x,x(1-x),x(1+x)\}$, let $b'=\{1,1+x,1+x^2\}$ and let $B=M_{b,b'}\operatorname{Id}$ (the change of basis matrix). Then the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $b'$ is $B.A.B^{-1}$.

Comment: If you have $T(1)$, $T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$, you’ve already done half of the work for the second part. One could compute the change of basis from the standard $(1,x,x^2)$ basis to the second one instead of starting over from scratch.

Comment: @amd You are right, of course. It happens that, at first, I only saw the second part. Only when I was about to post it, I saw that there was also another question.

Answer (score 0):

Denote $\mathcal B=\bigl\{1-x,\,x(1-x),\,x(1+x)\bigr\}$,  $\;\mathcal B'=\bigl \{1,\,1+x,\,1+x^2\bigr\}$. You have to compute the change of basis matrix $P$ from basis $\mathcal B$ to basis  $\mathcal B'$. Its columns are made up of the coordinates of vectors of  basis  $\mathcal B'$ in basis $\mathcal B$.

One easily finds that 
\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}1&=(1-x)+\tfrac12 x(1-x)+\tfrac12 x(1+x),\\[0.5ex]
1+x&= (1-x)+x(1-x)+x(1+x),\\[0.5ex]
1+x^2&=(1-x)+0\cdot x(1-x)+x(1+x),\end{aligned}\end{cases}
so the change of basis matrix is
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\\frac12&1&0\\\frac12&1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
You can either find its inverse with *Gauß-Jordan elimination*, or use the same method as for $P$:
\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}1-x&=2-(1+x),\\[0.5ex]
x(1-x)&= x-x^2=(1+x)-(1+x^2),\\[0.5ex]
x(1+x)&=-2x+0+(1+x)+(1+x^2),\end{aligned}\end{cases}
so the change of basis matrix from basis $\mathcal B'$ to basis  $\mathcal B $ is
$$P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&-2\\-1&1&1\\0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
There remains to compute matrix
$$ A'=P^{-1}AP. $$